# Google Chrome Sync Doesn't Persist Between Sessions

Tags: google-chrome, sync, onedrive, bookmarks

I had to reinstall windows after a BSOD loop on my current laptop. After restoring all my personal files from my backup, I installed Google Chrome as usual. I signed into my account and turned on sync but quickly found out that whenever I exit out of all my Chrome windows, if I then open Chrome later **I have to turn on synchronization again**. **This prevents the browser from syncing my bookmarks and startup page** but somehow retains my extensions.

I have also tried going without syncing by simply importing my local bookmark file. This leads to the same issue.

*Additional, potentially relevant information:*

After restoring my computer I signed up for OneDrive. I added all my desktop shortcuts to OneDrive, which resulted in a few of them generating synchronization errors due to authorization/permission due to copyright law or something. Chrome was one of those programs. Since then I've removed it from OneDrive and I've been trying to solve the issue with the OneDrive sync paused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this post for anyone who may experience this issue in the future...

What I initially thought was a sync error either in Chrome or OneDrive actually appears to have been a permissions issue with my Windows user profile. I was able to confirm this by running Chrome as admin, which worked as expected. So, I edited permissions for the "Bookmarks" and "Bookmarks.bak" files to allow full access for my user. My path to this location is:

C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

This solved the bookmarks issue, but I was still experiencing issues with extensions and my launch page. I had already reinstalled Chrome a couple times in the troubleshooting process, but tried again and made sure to delete my Google folders in Users\<Username>\AppData and C:\Program Files (x86) and then launch the installer as admin. This solved my issues after once again signing into the Chrome browser. My theory is that initially my permissions were tied to my old SID from before reinstalling Windows.