# Chrome requires admin access to populate bookmarks on opening

Tags: google-chrome, sync, administrator, bookmarks

After recently reinstalling windows, I've run into a problem when using Google Chrome. On normal startup it will open the browser as if for the first time without syncing tabs or bookmarks, but populating all extensions and logging into my main profile. However, if I run chrome as admin it populates bookmarks and runs normally.

Is there a way to:

1. Run chrome as admin by default without requiring me to allow access on the pop-up window that appears
2. Give my user account admin privileges for using chrome/accessing bookmarks
3. Solve this issue via another approach?

Edit: A second symptom of this issue is that chrome doesn't save my launch page (always takes me to Google) and launches the welcome page for one of my extensions every time it's opened without admin privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this for anyone who may experience this issue in the future...

According to my searching and anecdotal evidence, here are the answers to the questions I asked in the initial post:

1. No, the whole point of running as admin is to force user interaction to okay the process. However, you can configure an application to run as admin by default by right clicking > Properties > Shortcut > Advanced > Run as Administrator. This option can be set in a few places, for instance in the Compatibility tab.
2. It is possible to go folder by folder, assigning full access and forcing all files within to inherit these permissions. However, it appears to be bad practice to assign the admin role to a user account.
3. Reinstalling did the trick (even though I attempted this while troubleshooting). Make sure to delete the Chrome files that may still be present after uninstalling. [Here is another post detailing that process.](https://superuser.com/questions/1678106/google-chrome-sync-doesnt-persist-between-sessions/1680994#1680994)